# How can I access custom Textbox attributes in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, html, textbox

I am using/abusing CSS classes and custom html attributes to provide default data to a set of textboxes. The code-front for this looks like the following (with some supporting javascript to handle checking/setting the default data when the field is blank):

`<asp:TextBox ID="TXT_LenderName" class='defaultText' data-default='Institution Name'  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>`

This works.

I am working on the code-behind to process this form. I would like to be able to compare the value of the `TXT_LenderName.Text` to the value of the `data-default` attribute, but I haven't been able to find a way to get the value of a custom html attribute. Suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you use the [`defaultValue`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_defaultvalue.asp) instead?

Comment: DefaultValue would be a good way to do this as well, and at the time of this post, I was not aware of that attribute on text box controls. Am I correct to assume that this attribute is not available to the browser once the control is rendered?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is tested and worked

```
string customAttrDataDefault = TXT_LenderName.Attributes["data-default"];
txtpassword.Attributes.Add("value","Password value");
```

Comment: Is the `.ToString()` actually necessary for any reason? `.Attributes` is already of type `string` from what I can tell.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
TXT_LenderName.Attributes["AttributeName"]= value;//here get or set the value.
```

Comment: I had to use () instead of [] like this TXT_LenderName.Attributes("AttributeName") in order to work. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 4):

If the control, like the TextBox control inherits from the System.Web.UI.WebControls.Control class then it should have an Attributes property which is a name value pair collection of the control's attributes.