# How to retrieve HTML5 data-* Attributes using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, code-behind, custom-data-attribute

I have a asp checkbox in my form:

```
<asp:CheckBox id="option" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="checkChange" data-attributeA="somevalue1" data-attributeB="somevalue2" AutoPostBack="true" />`
```

In my `OnCheckedChanged` event I want to retrieve these two data-attributes.

```
protected void checkChange(object sender, EventArgs e) {}
```

How do I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I access custom Textbox attributes in ASP.Net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785946/how-can-i-access-custom-textbox-attributes-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The same approach in the link shared by @musefan will work for you.

I have created a CheckBox:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" dataAttributeA="Test Custom Attr A" dataAttributeB="Test Custom B" Text="Check it or dont" AutoPostBack="True" />
```

Then a method to handle the changed event:

```
 protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String customAttr1 = CheckBox1.Attributes["dataAttributeA"].ToString();
        String customAttr2 = CheckBox1.Attributes["dataAttributeB"].ToString();

        Response.Write("<h1> Custom Attributes A and B = " + customAttr1 + " " + customAttr2);

    }
```

And finally I have set the AutoPostBack property of the CheckBox to true, so It's change event will be triggered as soon as it's clicked.

I have obtained the expected result

> Custom Attributes A and B = Test Custom Attr A Test Custom B